# Which Informat Reads this time hh:mm:ss PM Or AM in SaS?

Tags: sas, format, informat

I can't Read a column from excel which like

```
9:32:18 AM
9:32:23 AM
9:34:31 AM
9:34:33 AM
4:53:56 PM
8:28:44 AM
8:35:19 AM
4:21:22 PM
8:37:50 AM
8:37:58 AM
8:38:16 AM
4:44:33 PM
```

in SAS Base 9.4 on Windows 10 
TimeZone +2

Comment: Have you tried `time.` informat? It should work in this case.

Comment: How are you getting the data from excel?  What does "can't read" mean?